# Two questions about pseudo equidistributed sequences modulo 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, arithmetic-functions, riemann-integration, equidistribution

Let $s_n$ a sequence of positive real numbers such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{s_n}=0$$
and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{s_{[nt]}}{s_n}=t,$$
for every real $t\in[0,1]$. See [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.1399v2.pdf), page 4.

> **Question 1.** Can you give a detailed proof of 
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{s_{[bt]}-s_{[at]}}{s_n}=b-a,$$
>   where $0\leq a<b\leq 1$?

If previous assumptions hold, then the sequence of ratios 
$$\frac{s_1}{s_n},\frac{s_2}{s_n},\ldots\frac{s_n}{s_n}$$
approach uniform distribution modulo one as $n\to\infty$, and we say that $s_n$ is **pseudodistributed mod 1**.

> **Question 2.** Let $s_n=\sigma(n)$, where $\sigma(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d$ is the **sum of divisor function**. Is this sequence pseudo equidistributed mod 1?

Answer (score 0):

Question $1$ is false. If $a$ is fixed, then $s_{\lfloor bt\rfloor}$ is a constant, meaning that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{s_{\lfloor bt\rfloor}-s_{\lfloor at\rfloor}}{s_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{s_{\lfloor bt\rfloor}}{s_n} - \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{s_{\lfloor at\rfloor}}{s_n}=s_{\lfloor bt\rfloor}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{s_n}-s_{\lfloor at\rfloor}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{s_n}=0-0=0$$

Comment: Then will be a typo that I write or in the paper, I don't know what say. Thanks @5xum